# Deleting... dialog box stays on screen for over a minute when deleting one small file

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

Every now and again I log into a Windows Server 2003 box with a remote desktop connection and delete one small file. When I do this, the Deleting... dialog box appears and remains on the screen for well over a minute.

After the dialog box disappears, if I delete another small file, the Deleting... dialog box appears then disappears quickly.

Why does it take so long to delete the first file after logging into a Windows Server 2003 box with a remote desktop connection?

Is there a trick to speeding it up?

Comment: Are you deleting the file from the remote computer or is it on a network share?

Comment: The file is on the Windows Server 2003 box's local drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the recycle bin.  When it's full windows needs to scan the entire bin for the oldest items to delete when adding a new item.

Answer (score 0):

I find it faster to delete from a command prompt, especially when deleting many files.

For example, to delete all file in a directory and  subdirectories

```
del /S /F *.*
```

Comment: You can insert star.star if you format the line as code. Put 4 spaces at the start of the line or select the text and use the code button in the toolbar. (You can't however do that in a comment as far as I know.)